# member variable problem when using 'const CString &' instead of LPCTSTR

Tags: c++

I thought const CString& and LPCTSTR are the same, but running the code below in VS2019 (with build option Character Set=Not Set), when I swap out the definition for m_str, it works using LPCTSTR but not when using const CString &. What is wrong here please?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>

class CTest
{
public:
    CTest(LPCTSTR str) : m_str(str) {}
    const CString& m_str;   // Invalid inside t2
    //LPCTSTR m_str;        //Valid inside t2
};
class CTest2
{
public:
    CTest2(CTest& t) : m_test(t) { std::cout << m_test.m_str << std::endl; }
    CTest &m_test;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CString s("Hello");
    CTest t(s);
    CTest2 t2(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CTest(LPCTSTR str) : m_str(str) {}` This initializes `m_str` with a reference to a temporary `CString` constructed from `str`, which then gets immediately destructed and leaves the reference dangling.

Comment: `LPCTSTR` is a `const char*` or `const wchar_t*` depending on compilation. Those are pointers. These are very different from references (denoted by the `&` symbol), so they aren't the same. Try changing `const CString& m_str;` to `const CString m_str;`